# Can mongodb inserts be made faster using the $hint and $natural operators

Tags: mongodb

I am aware that [indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/) slow down inserts as the indexes need to updated every time a new record is inserted.

For a collection with several indexes, is it possible to direct the insert operation to [use the `$hint` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/measure-index-use/) and force it to use the `$natural` index ? Will this speed up the inserts or am I better off dropping all indexes just to speed up the inserts?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

that `$natural` hint is telling mongo to ignore indexes on queries, it has nothing with insertions.
please note that you cannot turn off the indexes for period of time.
If you want to speed up your insertions, dropping your indexes is an option but it will affect your queries. a better option is to change the write concerns setting:
for instance, `"Unacknowledged"` will make the insertion faster as it won't wait for `mongod` to confirms the receipt of the write operation. I guess that the downside is clear.
take a look here:  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/

About indexes, it's never a good idea to have indexes that you don't need as they are slowing down insertions (as you already know) and they are biting your machine memory.

At the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/use-capped-collections-for-fast-writes-and-reads/), it is recommended to use `capped collections` to speed up the writes, you may want to consider it.

Comment: Note to those looking into capped collections: remember that they are _circular_. May save some headache if haven't read with attention the documentations.

Comment: Wait, where does it say you should use capped collections over normal collections "to speed up the writes"?

Comment: @Sammaye: browse to http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/use-capped-collections-for-fast-writes-and-reads/ and you'll find promises like "capped collections can receive very high-speed writes". there is a section that explain why.
About the write concerns, it will speed up the writes as not waiting for ack; the downside is obvious (I also wrote that in my answer)

Comment: Yea I misread your answer so I deleted that last comment but what it says there does not support using a capped collection over a normal collection defacto as you hint in your answer. There are very specific scenarios and cases for using capped collections, all that line says is that capped collections can receive high throughput, one main reason being that they have no index updating

Comment: Speeding up inserts: If replica sets are an option, you can configure a two node set using the primary for writes and the secondary for reads: http://docs.mongodb.org/master/applications/replication/